# How to disable a button in the non-custom tabs of excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I would like to disable a button in one of the default tabs of Excel.
More specifically the "Cut" button in the the home tab.

Similarly request on right click cell, row or column I could already implement by code:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars["Cell"].FindControl(Office_core.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 21, null, false, true).Enabled = false;
```

but it seems that the rules are different when accessing the button of the default tabs.

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars["Worksheet Menu Bar"].FindControl(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 21, null, false, true).Enabled = false
```

This is not returning an error and looks like the command that fits my needs.

Research so far:

• https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win013.htm seems a good guide but it's for custom buttons only.

• A lot information on the net is about custom tabs which is not my case.

• Maybe a refresh is needed after the modification but looping through Globals.Ribbons doesn't return the default ribbons. So I can't apply `invalidate()` to it. Also prior alterations on cell/row/column didn't need any form of refresh...